# How to solve Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel

I am using `laravel 6.2` and `maatwebsite/excel 3.1 to export to excel` but i got an error as:

> call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create().

How to fix this error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In version 3.1 Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store(). Please read the document https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check change log for current version that you are using. Please check the change log in this official website https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html